# Python argparse: separate options for positional arguments

Tags: python, argparse

i write a script that takes one or more input files. I want to be able to specify  options for the script (A and B) and for each of the input files separately (C and D).

Usage should look like:

```
script.py [-A] [-B]  [-C] [-D] file1 [[-C] [-D] file2] ...
```

How can it be done with `argparse`?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know how many input files you will have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usually, the question appeared to be not exactly what is needed.. Sorry.
Here is my working result (inspired by unutbu's answer) that allows also per-file options with arguments.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-A', action = 'store_true')
parser.add_argument('-B', action = 'store_true')
args, unk = parser.parse_known_args()

file_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
file_parser.add_argument('-C', action = 'store_true')
file_parser.add_argument('-D', action = 'store_true')
file_parser.add_argument('-V', "--variable-list")
file_parser.add_argument('file')

fargs=[]
n=len(unk)
while True:
        i=0
        for i in  range(n): # finding longest fully parsable tail
            Parsed, unkf = file_parser.parse_known_args(unk[i:n])
            if not unkf: break
        if i==n: # did not found parsable tail
            file_parser.parse_args(unk[0:n]) # cause error 
        else:
            fargs.append(Parsed)
            n=i
        if (n<=0): break
fargs.reverse()

print args
for argl in fargs:
        print argl
```

Calling this with:

```
myscript.py -A -B -C -D file1 -C -V a,b,c file
```

yields:

```
Namespace(A=True, B=True)
Namespace(C=True, D=True, file='file1', variable_list=None)
Namespace(C=True, D=False, file='file2', variable_list='a,b,c')
```

Answer (score 4):

If possible try [docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopt). It is much easier to use and has enough examples to get started.

Comment: Thanks! Impressive approach. However, my script is supposed to work at several computers with quite ancient python installed. So, unfortunately, standard solutions are preferred to elegant those...

Answer (score 4):

I've wanted to do this for a while, but never dreamt up a use case. You've found one: thank you!

You can do this with two-stages of argparsing.
In the first stage, you only look for `-A` or `-B` options.

In the second stage, you split up the remaining arguments into fragments (in this case using a generator function) and call `parse_args` on the fragments:

```
import argparse

def fileargs(args):
    result = []
    for arg in args:
        result.append(arg)
        if not arg.startswith('-'):
            yield result
            result = []

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-A', action = 'store_true')
parser.add_argument('-B', action = 'store_true')
args, unk = parser.parse_known_args()
print(args)

file_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
file_parser.add_argument('-C', action = 'store_true')
file_parser.add_argument('-D', action = 'store_true')
file_parser.add_argument('file')
for filearg in fileargs(unk):
    fargs = file_parser.parse_args(filearg)
    print(fargs)
```

then `test.py -A -B -C -D file1 -C file2` yields

```
Namespace(A=True, B=True)
Namespace(C=True, D=True, file='file1')
Namespace(C=True, D=False, file='file2')
```

Comment: Thank you! Clear, simple and exactly addresses the asked question. Indeed i needed also to use option arguments for files, but that somehow dropped out from the questions formulation. Sorry. Please see also my answer, that was found after trying your code...

Answer (score 1):

My, this answer is convoluted:

```
import sys

#Unforunately, you can't split up positional arguments in a reasonable way if you
#don't know about all of them...  Count positional arguments (files)

def how_many_files(lst):
    return sum(1 for x in lst if not x.startswith('-'))

args = sys.argv[1:]
Nfiles = how_many_files(args)

import argparse

#Create our own NameSpace class so that we can have an easy handle on the
#attributes that the namespace actually holds.
class MyNameSpace(argparse.Namespace,dict):
    def __init__(self):
        argparse.Namespace.__init__(self)
        dict.__init__(self)

    def __setattr__(self,k,o):
        argparse.Namespace.__setattr__(self,k,o)
        self[k] = o

class MyParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.my_parents = kwargs.get('parents',[])
        argparse.ArgumentParser.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

class FooAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self,parser,namespace,value,option_string=None):
        ref = namespace.pop('accumulated',{})
        try:
            del namespace.accumulated
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        #get a new namespace and populate it with the arguments we've picked up
        #along the way        
        new_namespace = self.__default_namespace(parser)
        for k,v in namespace.items():
            setattr(new_namespace,k,v)
            delattr(namespace,k)  #delete things from `namespace.__dict__`

        namespace.clear() #also remove things from the dictionary side.
        namespace.accumulated = ref
        new_namespace.file = value
        ref[value] = new_namespace

    def __default_namespace(self,parser):
        n = argparse.Namespace()
        for parent in parser.my_parents:
            parent.parse_args([],namespace=n)
        return n


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-A',action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-B',action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-C',action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-D',action='store_true')


parser2 = MyParser(parents=[parser],conflict_handler='resolve')
for i in range(Nfiles):
    parser2.add_argument('files%d'%i,action=FooAction,default=argparse.SUPPRESS)


n = parser2.parse_args(args,namespace = MyNameSpace())
for k,v in n.accumulated.items():
    print k,v
```

Calling this with:

```
~ $ python test.py -A foo bar -A -B -C qux
```

yields:

```
qux Namespace(A=True, B=True, C=True, D=False, file='qux')
foo Namespace(A=True, B=False, C=False, D=False, file='foo')
bar Namespace(A=False, B=False, C=False, D=False, file='bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `action=append` option will probably help. This will let you specify an option multiple times and all arguments with a specific option will be stored in their respective lists.

... here's a example, lets call it `sample.py`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-c", "--cfilein", action="append")
    parser.add_argument("-d", "--dfilein", action="append")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print args.cfilein
    print args.dfilein

Execute: ./sample.py -c f1 -d f2 -c f3 -d f4
Output:  ['f1', 'f3']
         ['f2', 'f4']
```

Check out: http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#action ...
Hope this helps ...

Comment: with custom actions, something like this could be made to work pretty easily, but it forces you to specify an unnecessary `-f` before each file.